# Building is okay with my Xcode but Fastlane is not

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I have some pods in my project and it is working but when i run simple test with fastlane i am getting error in terminal something below :

```
[12:05:55]: ▸ ** BUILD FAILED **
[12:05:55]: ▸ 2021-08-15 12:05:55.057 xcodebuild[3300:92876] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[12:05:55]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fb08dc372d0>
[12:05:55]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[12:05:55]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[12:05:55]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb0cdc1a600>{number = 1, name = main}
[12:05:55]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[12:05:55]: ▸ 2021-08-15 12:05:55.058 xcodebuild[3300:92876] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[12:05:55]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fb08dc411a0>
[12:05:55]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[12:05:55]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[12:05:55]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb0cdc1a600>{number = 1, name = main}
[12:05:55]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[12:05:55]: ▸ Testing failed:
[12:05:55]: ▸   The linked framework 'Pods_MyPayDemo.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.
[12:05:55]: ▸   The linked framework 'Pods_MyPayBitionDemo.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.
[12:05:55]: ▸   Testing cancelled because the build failed.
[12:05:55]: ▸ ** TEST FAILED **
** BUILD FAILED **
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting derived data fixed my problem.